# Can't start JNLP app over https

Tags: https, javafx, jnlp

During deployment our JavaFX-based app using JNLP I discovered very strange thing.

1. I can't launch it when server are running over SSL(web server certificate are valid, all jars are signed)
2. Java permissions was changed to accept jars from this host

In same time, plain http working perfectly. After realizing this strange behaviour, I enabled verbose logging in java console and found 2 much different approaches which I can't explain.

For https version javaws translated URI from jnlp into local bounded links with file:// prefix

```
<jnlp spec="6.0+" codebase="file:/var/tmp/" href="file:/var/tmp/sniper-client.jnlp">
  <information>
   <title>MyApp</title>
  <vendor>MyCompany</vendor>
   <homepage href="null"/>
<description>MyApp</description>
  <offline-allowed/>
 </information>
   <security>
     <all-permissions/>
   </security>
   <update check="background" policy="always"/>
   <resources>
    <javafx-runtime version="2.2+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
<java java-vm-args="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.6.0+"/>
<jar href="file:/var/tmp/myapp.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
<jar href="file:/var/tmp/lib/afterburner.fx-1.5.1.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
<jar href="file:/var/tmp/lib/commons-math3-3.3.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
<jar href="file:/var/tmp/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
<jar href="file:/var/tmp/lib/joda-time-2.3.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
<jar href="file:/var/tmp/lib/logback-classic-1.1.0.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
<jar href="file:/var/tmp/lib/logback-core-1.1.0.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
```

but for plain http all links was correctly transformed into http bound URLs:

```
  <jnlp spec="6.0+" codebase="http://server:9800/client/" href="http://server:9800/client/myapp.jnlp">
   <information>
     <title>MyApp</title>
     <vendor>MyCompany</vendor>
    <homepage href="null"/>
     <description>MyApp</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
   <security>
     <all-permissions/>
   </security>
   <update check="background" policy="always"/>
  <resources>
     <javafx-runtime version="2.2+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
      <java java-vm-args="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.6.0+"/>
       <jar href="http://server:9800/client/myapp.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
       <jar href="http://server:9800/client/lib/afterburner.fx-1.5.1.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
       <jar href="http://server:9800/client/lib/commons-math3-3.3.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
       <jar href="http://server:9800/client/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
```

SO question is what is going on and how make this app works over https?

Comment: I am having similar issues. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: No, I dont:( Sorry about this.